# Open netCDF file from the Modis Aqua L3Bin

Tags: python, numpy

I am unable to read the netCDF file that I downloaded from the Modis Aqua L3Bin. An example would be A20140602014090.L3b_MO_NSST.nc from the website: http://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi/

I want to open the netCDF file and store it in a 2x2 numpy array so I can subset it to my area of interest. Any help or pointers are most appreciated.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

data = 'ModisAqua/A20140602014090.L3b_MO_NSST.nc'
fh = Dataset(data, 'r')
```

Comment: These files have compound types so you probably need to write your own code against the NetCDF API. You can see examples in Seadas source, or potentially use ncdump to extract.